# Does a verb "to downhold" exist?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

There is a verb "***to uphold***", which I think means "*to support*", "*to sustain*".

But I didn't find an instance where the verb "***to downhold***" would be used. Is it a non-existing word? There is a [questionable entry](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/downhold) for the noun, but I'm not sure it's being used either.

Comment: No it does not, but that's the kind of English idiosyncrasy that comedians love to exploit.  For example, you can be "overwhelmed" and you can be "underwhelmed", but you can't just be "whelmed".

Comment: In context it would probably be understood, but most native speakers (and almost all dictionaries) wouldn't consider it a "valid word". So I suggest you avoid it, and stick to ***hold down*** the same as everyone else.

Comment: @Andrew: Sure you can, it's just archaic.

Comment: @NathanTuggy well color me *whelmed*.  :)

Comment: I dunno, but I would use it with inverted commas.

Comment: The close vote here is entirely frivolous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "downhold" is not in widespread use. Note that it does not appear in several other dictionaries ([Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=downhold)). It is evidently a recent coining.

Note also the [ngrams graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uphold%2Cdownhold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuphold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownhold%3B%2Cc0)